# Openvpn - one server private key / multiple clients keys

Tags: openvpn, encryption

In therory, an asymmetric encryption allows a single public key to be associated with only one private key.

However, in OpenVPN, you can create certificats for multiple clients with only one server certificat associated.

How is it possible?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority

Comment: Is that a question?

Comment: I understand your view point. With a CA, the server and the clients will authenticate each other, even if clients have different keys, as only the signature is verified. However, for the key exchange part (SSL/TLS) used by OpenVPN, I see the following problem : how it will works as the clients have different keys and the server only one private key...

Comment: I think you don't understand how CAs work.

Comment: The client /server will verify the signature of the presented certificate using the public key of the CA. Indeed, the signature was made using the private key of the CA. This is great for mutual authentication as it is used by OpenVPN. My problem is not here. I just want to understand how OpenVPN will handle the encryption communication, as there is multiple clients with different keys, and only one server private key

Comment: The CA-related certificates are used for initial authentication and bootstrapping the connection, after which new session keys are generated, which are used for actual data encryption.

Comment: It should also be said that symmetric ciphers are used for data, not the keypairs.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. Can you confirm that the CA-related certificates are only used for authentication and bootstrapping the connection, and after authentication, the server will send a new certificate to the client with a public key corresponding to the actual server private key?